# Adding Null check is throwing a series of compile errors

Tags: java

I was testing a  program for CPU usage check and I got a null pointer exception, so I added null check. When I added null check I started getting series of errors. Here is the code:

```
double ideltime=Double.parseDouble(cpuIdle.trim());
**String idelTimeStr=formatter.format(ideltime);
if(idelTimeStr!=null)** 
double usuage=temp - Double.parseDouble(idelTimeStr);           
cpuUsage = formatter.format(usuage);
```

The Highlighted lines show the null check added. Compilation error after this null check is as follows:

```
CPUUsage.java:29: error: '.class' expected
                        double usuage=temp - Double.parseDouble(idelTimeStr);
                               ^
CPUUsage.java:29: error: not a statement
                        double usuage=temp - Double.parseDouble(idelTimeStr);
                        ^
CPUUsage.java:29: error: illegal start of expression
                        double usuage=temp - Double.parseDouble(idelTimeStr);
                                     ^
CPUUsage.java:29: error: ';' expected
                        double usuage=temp - Double.parseDouble(idelTimeStr);
```

Please help in resolving this.

Comment: it seems like you are missing the curly brackets after the if, this will cause the compiler to notice that the variable `usage` can´t ever be used, aswell as it´s not existing anymore if you call `formatter.format(usuage);`

Comment: can you give full code.

Comment: @KevinEsche 's observation is correct I just tried it, After adding curly braces it solves it a bit, please post full code.

Comment: Shouldn't `if(idelTimeStr!=null)` have an opening `{`...?  Maybe a closing `}` as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can ommit the curly braces when there is only one statement:

```
if (condition) 
    statement;
```

is identical to

```
if (condition) { 
    statement;
}
```

This is defined by the grammar in the [JLS Chapter 14: Blocks and Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html). The relevant production terms are:

```
IfThenStatement:
    if ( Expression ) Statement
...

Statement:
    StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement 
...

StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement:
    Block 
    EmptyStatement 
    ExpressionStatement 
...
```

Finally, an `ExpressionStatement` is something like an assignment or a method invocation, but **not** a variable declaration. Variable declarations require a **block**.

[JLS 14.2: Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2):

> A block is a sequence of statements, local class declarations, and **local variable declaration** statements **within braces**.

and [JLS 14.4: Local Variable Declaration Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4):

> Every local variable declaration statement is immediately contained by a block.

Since you are declaring `double usuage = ...` you need the curly braces in this case:

```
if(idelTimeStr != null) {
    double usuage=temp - Double.parseDouble(idelTimeStr);
}
```

is **not** identical to

```
if(idelTimeStr != null)
    double usuage=temp - Double.parseDouble(idelTimeStr);
```

With the curly braces, your program is *syntactically* fine, but then you need to consider that the `usuage` variable is only visible within the block, so you will need to add more of your code inside the curly braces (or declare and initialize `usuage` with a default value outside of the `if` block).

In any case, I [suggest to **always** use braces even if there is only one statement](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/curly-braces/).

Comment: Your resolution and explanation is perfect. But at this situation i m getting another error. Null pointer exception is getting thrown one line after another. Please see the error:

Comment: [root@IoT6 home]# javac CPUUsage.java
[root@IoT6 home]# java CPUUsage
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at CPUUsage.main(CPUUsage.java:27)
what is the CPU usage
[root@IoT6 home]# javac CPUUsage.java
[root@IoT6 home]# java CPUUsage
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at CPUUsage.main(CPUUsage.java:28)
what is the CPU usage
[root@IoT6 home]#
 See full code:

Comment: String cpuIdle = "";
int temp = 100;
String cpuUsage = "";
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
if(reader.readLine()!=null)
{
//cpuIdle = reader.readLine(); 
double ideltime=Double.parseDouble((reader.readLine()).trim());
String idelTimeStr=formatter.format(ideltime);
if(idelTimeStr!=null) 
{ double usuage=temp - Double.parseDouble(idelTimeStr);   
cpuUsage = formatter.format(usuage);

Comment: Its difficult to read code in comments - please ask a new question for that issue, but be sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it to avoid downvotes and closure ;-) I do see some issues, like you are checking `reader.readLine()` for null and then afterwards calling `reader.readLine()` again, but be aware that `readLine()` is similar to an iterator which returns the **next** line on subsequent calls